# How to make the picture above the horizontal line

Tags: html, css

How to move the icon above more and cover the horizontal line at the same time? I've tried to add `min-height` at the intro.css `.intro__logo{ }`, but it occured another problem, there was a white block between the navbar and the horizontal line, I have no idea how to solve it.

[image: The design pattern]

[image: My work]

```css
.header__nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.header__menu,
.header__social {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 15px;
}

.header__menu {
  gap: 90px;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: var(--second-primary-color);
}

.header__menu span {
  color: var(--background-color);
}

.header__social {
  gap: 10px;
}

.header__social img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.intro {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.intro hr {
  border: 1px solid var(--primary-color);
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.intro__logo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 64px;
}

.intro__logo img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 3px solid var(--primary-color);
  background-color: var(--background-color);
  object-fit: contain;
  z-index: 2;
}

.intro__page img {
  width: 1280px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="header__nav">
    <ul class="header__menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#about-me">About Me</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#last-activity">Last Activity</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#policy">Policy</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Blank Blank
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#donate">Donate</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#feedback">Feedback</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="header__social">
      <li>
        <img src="public/icon-fb.svg" alt="facebook" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="public/icon-ig.svg" alt="instagram" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="public/icon-youtube.svg" alt="youtube" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="public/icon-line.svg" alt="line" />
      </li>
    </ul>

  </nav>
</header>
<section class="intro">
  <div class="intro__logo">
    <img src="public/logo.svg" alt="logo"/>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="intro__page">
    <img src="public/cat-6960532_1280 2.png" alt="intro__background" />
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Note that `<hr>` elements should not be used for the sole purpose of creating visual horizontal lines. They're meant for semantically denoting thematic breaks in the content. If you just need a decorative line that doesn't denote a thematic break, just use CSS on an existing element or a non-semantic `<div>`.

Comment: Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers. It's not clear whether one resolved your issue based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the z-index so it overlaps the HR element. Then push the top down. Adjust the HR accordingly.

```css
.intro__logo {
  position: relative; /* or you can try absolute */
  top: -20px; /* adjust this value as needed to move up */
  z-index: 10; /* ensures it's above the horizontal line */
}
    
hr {
  margin-top: 0; 
  margin-bottom: 0; 
}
```

Comment: Well, I put the scripts `.intro__logo{ }` to the `.intro { }`, and it works！Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the logo inside the nav menu, give `position: relative;` to the nav and then to the logo:

```css
.logoCovering{
    position: absolute;
    top: /* optional, usally 0*/;
    left: /* optional, usally 0*/;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

In this way, your logo will be centered, the nav will not recognize the logo and you will get the desired alignment

Answer (score 0):

Not a great responsive "wrap" here but I only based that on your picture; you can address that separately methinks.  Here I used grids to place the logo so that it visually stays in the same place no matter how you re-size your page or zoom.  Notice how it overlaps the container below it also due to the use of the grids this way.

I used a sample cat background image just so it is visually "there".  I altered the `<hr` to be a span and styled in as an inline-block as that is slightly more "proper" for a visual.

FWIW not a fan of the double underscores in classes as they can be hard to discern from single/triple visually IMHO.  I kept some of yours but used dashed classes to clearly illustrate the points here, naming what are essentially "containers" as `-container` classes. or `-block` for blocks of elements.

No `position:` here in the CSS to be a bit more modern in approach; a super fast answer and not super "clean" but more to base from.

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: #c7b198;
  --second-primary-color: #ff77ff;
  --background-color: #ffff00;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 2.5em repeat(3, 1em);
  width: 100vw;
}

.header-container {
  grid-row: 1 span 3;
}

.bar-container {
  grid-row: 2;
  height: 0.25em;
  width: 100%;
}

.intro-container {
  grid-row: 4 span 2;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.bar-container .intro-bar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
}

.header-container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: #d0d0d040;
  height: 3.5em;
}

.nav-block {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1em repeat(10, auto) 1em;
  grid-template-rows: 2em 1.5em 1em;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-block {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2 / 8;
  background-color: #00ffff20;
}

.logo-block {
  grid-row: 1 span 3;
  grid-column: 5 / 5;
}

.social-block {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 8 / 11;
}

.header__menu,
.header__social {
  list-style: none;
}

.header__menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr) 4em repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 2em;
}

.header__menu>* {
  /* just to show what is where */
  border: solid 1px;
}

.header__menu a {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* maybe... */
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: var(--prmary-color);
}

.header__social {
  grid-column: 7 span 4;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  align-self: end;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
  background-color: #ffff4040;
}

.header__menu {
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: var(--second-primary-color);
  line-height: 3em;
}

.header__social img {
  width: 1.25em;
  height: 1.25em;
  color: #0000ff;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.55em;
}

.intro {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header-logo {
  margin-top: 0.25em;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: dashed 2px #0000ff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.header-logo .logo-element {
  width: 5.625em;
  height: 5.625em;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 3px solid var(--primary-color);
  background-color: var(--background-color);
  z-index: 1;
}

.intro-container .intro__page {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* background-image:url("public/cat-6960532_1280 2.png");*/
  background-image: url("https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/picture-element/images/kitten-small.png");
  background-size: cover;
}

.intro__page img[alt="intro__background"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar-container">
  <span class="intro-bar" />
</div>
<header class="header-container">
  <nav class="header__nav nav-block">
    <ul class="header__menu menu-block">
      <li>
        <a href="#about-me">About Me</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#last-activity">Last Activity</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#policy">Policy</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="header-logo-x"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#donate">Donate</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#feedback">Feedback</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="header-logo logo-block">
      <div class="logo-element">
        <img class="header-logo-image" src="public/logo.svg" alt="logo" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="header__social social-block">
      <li>
        <img src="public/icon-fb.svg" alt="facebook" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="public/icon-ig.svg" alt="instagram" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="public/icon-youtube.svg" alt="youtube" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="public/icon-line.svg" alt="line" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<section class="intro-container">
  <div class="intro__page">
    <img src="public/cat-6960532_1280 2.png" alt="intro__background" />
  </div>
</section>
```